# Swagger xml parameter tag in query

Tags: c#, xml, swagger

I am trying to add parameters of query type to my swagger. In other projects I was able to achieve with in yaml with the following notation:

```
parameters:
 - name: currentPage
 in: query
```

Now we are using C# in Visual Studio and we are forced to use XML. In order to get similar results I arrive to this:

```
<param name = "id" in = "query">GUID</param>
```

But it is not working. An odd thing if that even if I remove the in part the parameter isn't working either ex:

```
<param name = "id">GUID</param>
```

The complete remark including the signature of the function is:

```
/// <summary>
/// .....
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// .....
/// </remarks>
/// <param name = "id" in = "query">GUID</param>
/// <response code="200">OK</response>        
/// <response code="404">Not Found</response>        
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IEnumerable<.....> Get()
```

Do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a while, but finally got through it. In order to get query parameters added you need to add it the the method signature with the [FromQuery] annotation

```
public IEnumerable<Object> Get(
            [FromQuery] Guid Id,
            [FromQuery] DateTime RequestDate,
            [FromQuery] DateTime ExpirationDate,
            [FromQuery] string RequestedBy,
            [FromQuery] string PPEDD,
            [FromQuery] string SecurityConsultant,
            [FromQuery] string Status,
            [FromQuery] Guid TenantId,
            [FromQuery] Guid SubscriptionId,
            [FromQuery] string ResourceGroup,
            [FromQuery] string ResourceId
        )
```